# Angularjs Get value from http.get

Tags: angularjs, http, promise

I need to get value from http.get function but I don't know how.
Please help.

here is my code

```
$http.get(base_url+"user/feach_one")
   .then(function (response) {$scope.my = response.data;

     $scope.email=$scope.my.email;
     console.log("email from get:"+$scope.email);

});

console.log("Get email from outside:"+$scope.email);
```

This is the result in console:

```
Get email from outside:undefined
myangular.js:90 email from get:myemail@yahoo.com
```

Comment: You are doing it right, you will be able to get the value from outside the ".then" but only once it is resolved. What are you trying to do ? The console.log outside is called before the request is resolved but the value is set in your scope object

Comment: Make sure url is correct - Debug it - see browser console error type

Answer (score 1):

`$http` is an **asynchronous** call so this line:

```
console.log("Get email from outside:"+$scope.email);
```

Can be executed before `$http.get( ...)`. You should put in in the `.then` statement of the `$http` call:

```
$http.get(base_url+"user/feach_one").then(function (response) {
    $scope.my = response.data;
    $scope.email=$scope.my.email;
    console.log("email from get:"+$scope.email);
    console.log("Get email from outside:"+$scope.email);
});
```

Comment: my quesiton is how to get it. from the OUTSIDE

Comment: @Vuong Once the promise will be resolved, you will be able to use it with  `$scope.email`, as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't work because inside the `$http.then` function, `$scope` does not refer to the same `$scope` you're trying to access from outside the function. In order to make it work, you either need to put your `response.data` on the $parent scope, like so:

```
.then(function (response) {$scope.$parent.my = response.data;...}
```

Or you can return a value from within your `.then` function and assign that to your `$scope` within the controller (assuming you're using a service for the `$http` request).

```
function makeHttpReq(okcallback, errorCallback) {

    $http.get(base_url+"user/feach_one")
      .then(function (response) {
        okCallback(response.data)
    });
```

And then you can call the function in your controller like so:

```
makeHttpReq(function (data) {
    $scope.my = data;
}
```